# mysql php ssl connect certificate verify failed

Tags: mysql, php, ssl

I have followed this steps to add mysql ssl support on **Server A**:

```
# Generate a CA key and certificate with SHA1 digest
openssl genrsa 2048 > ca-key.pem
openssl req -sha1 -new -x509 -nodes -days 3650 -key ca-key.pem > ca-cert.pem

# Create server key and certficate with SHA1 digest, sign it and convert
# the RSA key from PKCS #8 (OpenSSL 1.0 and newer) to the old PKCS #1 format
openssl req -sha1 -newkey rsa:2048 -days 730 -nodes -keyout server-key.pem > server-req.pem
openssl x509 -sha1 -req -in server-req.pem -days 730  -CA ca-cert.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -set_serial 01 > server-cert.pem
openssl rsa -in server-key.pem -out server-key.pem

# Create client key and certificate with SHA digest, sign it and convert
# the RSA key from PKCS #8 (OpenSSL 1.0 and newer) to the old PKCS #1 format
openssl req -sha1 -newkey rsa:2048 -days 730 -nodes -keyout client-key.pem > client-req.pem
openssl x509 -sha1 -req -in client-req.pem -days 730 -CA ca-cert.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -set_serial 01 > client-cert.pem
openssl rsa -in client-key.pem -out client-key.pem
```

**Server A**
nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf

```
bind-address            = 0.0.0.0

[client]
ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/ca-cert.pem

[mysqld]
ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/ca-cert.pem
ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem
```

and test SSL support

```
mysql -u root -p
mysql> show variables like "%ssl%";
This is resoult from my ubuntu 14.04 test machine

mysql> show variables like "%ssl%";
+---------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                      |
+---------------+----------------------------+
| have_openssl  | YES                        |
| have_ssl      | YES                        |
| ssl_ca        | /etc/mysql/ca-cert.pem     |
| ssl_capath    |                            |
| ssl_cert      | /etc/mysql/server-cert.pem |
| ssl_cipher    |                            |
| ssl_crl       |                            |
| ssl_crlpath   |                            |
| ssl_key       | /etc/mysql/server-key.pem  |
+---------------+----------------------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Server B** nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf

```
[client]
ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/ca-cert.pem
ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/client-cert.pem
ssl-key=/etc/mysql/client-key.pem
```

**Server B:**
php script with which I'm testing:

```
$con=mysqli_init();
if (!$con){
    die("mysqli_init failed");
}

mysqli_ssl_set($con, "/var/www/certs/client-key.pem","/var/www/certs/client-cert.pem","/var/www/certs/ca-cert.pem",NULL, "AES256-SHA");

if (!mysqli_real_connect(
    $con,"127.0.0.1","user", 'password',"db", 3306)){
    die("Connect Error: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
mysqli_close($con);
```

Error which I'm getting:

```
PHP Warning:  mysqli_real_connect(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in ...
```

I'm running php script on Server B and mysql db is on server A.

When I try to connect over console from Server B to A it connects.
Code:

```
mysql -h SERVER_A_IP -P 3306 -uuser -ppassword
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because by default, OpenSSL tries to verify the certificate chain for your certificate. Your certificate is self-signed, that is, no other entity has verified it, and that is why certificate verification fails in OpenSSL.

In order to disable certificate verification, you need to add `MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL_DONT_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT` flag to the `mysqli_real_connect()` call.

The reason why your `mysql` test works is that you connect without SSL on that test. You need to enable SSL separately with `mysql` for testing it.

Comment: you are right, it is working. is it mysql security exposed if I use that option or do you recommend something else?

Comment: In this case I don't think there are any security implications, since you have the server certficate already in the client end. This has security issues in a case when the other end presents a self-signed certificate and you have no means of verifying the certificate.

Comment: I have attempted a connection to my workstation (127.0.0.1) and get this same error. Adding the **MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL_DONT_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT** flag does not fix the problem. My machine is Ubuntu 18 running MySQL 8.0 and PHP 7.2

Comment: Please add a new question with all the necessary details in serverfault. It is impossible to help with the information above.